# How do I get a QGraphicsRectItem's location during a mouseMove?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a subclass of QGraphicsRectItem. The mouseMoveEvent handler looks like this:

```
void BTNodeGraphicsItem::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* event)
{
    QGraphicsRectItem::mouseMoveEvent(event);
    qDebug() << rect().x() << " " << rect().y();
}
```

The item drags like I expect. But the qDebug statement outputs the same coordinates as I drag it. Shouldn't the rect be changing as it is dragged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the position in coordinates that are relative to the graphics item. To get coordinates in another perspective, use something like `mapToScene(rect())`